# Cohomology and impossible ﬁgures

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

In connection with the MO question [Occurrences of (co)homology in other disciplines and/or nature](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60108/occurrences-of-cohomology-in-other-disciplines-and-or-nature) I recalled Roger Penrose's “On the cohomology of impossible ﬁgures": http://upcommons.upc.edu/revistes/bitstream/2099/1062/1/st17-05-a2-ocr.pdf (see also http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1039540768 - "Peeking at the Impossible" by Chris Mortensen). I'm curious whether this interesting idea was further developed.
Are there any more recent papers on this subject?

Comment: There is [an old thread about this on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51525/264), but no additional papers are given, unfortunately.